# Eclipse Java oxygen - import sun.dc.pr.PathStroker cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, automation

When I finished the build path and added external jars and run the script config.properties, it popped up an error saying
import sun.dc.pr.PathStroker cannot be resolved in reporter.java resource file.
Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

Solution-1: Clean build and Run again.

Solution-2: Restart Eclipse IDE and again added external jars then Compile and Run.